# Simple way to watch a video from an external domain on my second domain?

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor

Simple way to watch a video from an external domain on my second domain ?
I did try to embedded the video but it doesn't work so probably i need to change something on the source domain of the video but i don't know what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon I have found a solution. It turns out that, instead of using an `<iframe>` to play video's you should be using `<video>` as seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

So instead of

```
<iframe src="https://havanamedia.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/video-salsa-classes.mp4" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="400px" width="600px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You should do:

```html
<video name="myiFrame" height="400px" width="600px" controls allowfullscreen>
    <source src="https://havanamedia.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/video-salsa-classes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Hope this helps! If not please comment

Comment: Your source's src contains a "/" before https which breaks the example at least in Firefox.